# WCF list return type conversion error

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I have created a very simple web service that returns a List Containing 3 items with 3 attributes each.
However when I call the method which should return the List I get a type conversion error.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'AlumniReference.RefDataList[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AlumniReference.RefDataList>'
```

IF someone can point our where I have gone wrong, I'll be able to sleep tonight.
I am using VS2010.

```
[DataContract]
public class RefDataList
{
    [DataMember]
    public string KEY { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string TEXT1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string TEXT2 { get; set; }

}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IAlumni
{ 
    [OperationContract]
    List<RefDataList> GetRefDataList(String RefData);
}

public class Alumni : IAlumni
{
    public List<RefDataList> GetRefDataList(string RefData)
    {
        List<RefDataList> thelist = new List<RefDataList>();
         thelist.Add(new RefDataList()
                    {
                        KEY = RefData,
                        TEXT1 = "One",
                        TEXT2 = "Ten"
                    });
         thelist.Add(new RefDataList()
                    {
                        KEY = "2",
                        TEXT1 = RefData,
                        TEXT2 = "Twenty"
                    });
         thelist.Add(new RefDataList()
                    {
                        KEY = "3",
                        TEXT1 = "Three",
                        TEXT2 = RefData
                    });
        return thelist;
    }

}
```

Web page:

```
proxy = new AlumniReference.AlumniClient();
List<AlumniReference.RefDataList> TitleList = new List<AlumniReference.RefDataList>();
TitleList = proxy.GetRefDataList("titlelist"); //This is the line with he issue.
```

Comment: Try this : TitleList = proxy.GetRefDataList("titlelist").ToList();

Comment: Thank you Sambath
Further investigation has shown that VS seems to think GetRefData is returning an Array.  This further strengthened by trying your line. I receive the following:
'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found
I don't understand why VS thinks GetRefDataList is returning an Array.

Comment: try to refer direct object in wcf service. How you are return from wcf service same as follow on web page also...